# XSL:FO Page-Seqence on left page

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Hello guys I want to configure my page-master that every "page-sequence" starts on a left page.

```
         <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Inhalt-rechtsLeerseite" odd-or-even="odd" blank-or-not-blank="blank" page-position="last"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Inhalt-links" odd-or-even="even"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Inhalt-rechts" odd-or-even="odd"/>
```

But I get no blank page on the end of the sequence . I also tried  nothing happpens.

I hope someone can help me. I use antenna house.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="auto-odd">`.  See 
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#initial-page-number

The initial values for `initial-page-number` and `force-page-count` are both `auto`, for the combined effect that page numbers just increment across page sequences.  Assuming that your first page number is "1" and an odd-page, then `force-page-count="even"` on every `fo:page-sequence` will mean that the next `fo:page-sequence` also starts on an odd-numbered page.  (Note that AH Formatter offers extended values for `force-page-count` for more control over the page count of the page sequence and/or the entire document: https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.force-page-count).

Instead of or as well as using `force-page-count` on the *preceding* `fo:page-sequence`, you can use `initial-page-number="auto-odd"` on the *current* page sequence to force the page sequence to start on an odd page.

Once you've got that working, you might want to remove `odd-or-even="odd"` and `page-position="last"` from your first `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` since you likely now won't be producing any odd-numbered pages as the last pages of your page sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add force-page-count property to page-sequence if you want even number of pages to be generated even if there is not enough content. You have to define page master for blank page as well.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#force-page-count